# Image Picker with Masonry

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-masonry

I am trying to combine [Image-picker](http://rvera.github.io/image-picker/) with [Masonry](https://github.com/desandro/masonry), but I met some problems with that.

My javascript is

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#image_picker").imagepicker();

    var msnry = new Masonry( '#container', {
      itemSelector: '.item',
    });
  });
```

and my HTML is

```
<div id="container js-masonry">
  <select multiple="multiple" class="image-picker masonry" id="image_picker">
    <div class="item"><option data-img-src="http://image_1.jpg">Img_1</option></div>
    <div class="item"><option data-img-src="http://image_2.jpg">Ime_2</option></div>
  </select>
</div>
```

The result shows that the image picker works fine, but it seems Masonry doesn't work.

There is a huge blank between the the first row and the second row of images.

Is there anyone who has the experience that can help me to fix it.

Thank you very much.

---

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Had Similar problem.. this link helped. http://jsfiddle.net/huanlin/mgvrc/

```
var $container = $('.image_picker_selector');
// initialize
$container.imagesLoaded(function () {
    $container.masonry({
        columnWidth: 30,
        itemSelector: '.thumbnail'
    });
});
```

you will have to use imagesLoaded plugin.. that way you apply masonry after images are loaded. http://imagesloaded.desandro.com/

Comment: Thanks, I found that's because I didn't enable the module..My bad